# What is wrong with this code in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get plain text out of value stored in variable like this

```
var lb = $(this).attr("htmllabel");
var text = $(this).html(lb);
alert(text);
```

When the alert popup it give result as object[Object] but I was expecting the actual string after application of the function.

Can anyone help me in this? Thanks.

Comment: If you pass a value to `.html`, it sets the content of the DOM element and returns a jQuery object (fluent interface). You should use HTML5 `data-` attributes btw.

Comment: "htmllabel" isn't a standard attribute; are you using a custom attribute? Can you show us the relevant HTML?

Comment: It's probably returning the DOM node that you inserted the html into, in which case you'd need to do `text.html()` to get what you inserted.

Comment: @dSquared: yeah I am using custom attribute it looks like this `<option value='E4' htmllabel='&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Test</b> <br /> Test 1 results'>` and I m try to convert it into plain text too so that all tags are removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(this).html(lb)`

This line is **setting** the html of whatever `this` is to whatever is stored in `lb`.  It then returns the jquery object for chaining purposes.

If you want the `html` of `this` then you just call `$(this).html()` with no parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code on the second line is setting something not getting something ...

Can you include your HTML and the actual data you want in the alert box and this might help shape the answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for the html method:

http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

As you can see from the documentation your code is setting the html for `this` and then returning a jQuery object.  What is it that you want to display exactly?

Comment: I am using custom attribute and it looks like this `<option value='E4' htmllabel='&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Test</b> <br /> Test 1 results'>` and I m trying to convert it into plain text too so that all tags are removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to get the value of your custom attribute "htmllabel", you can do the following:

```
var val = $(this).attr("htmllabel");
alter(val);
```

As a side note; I would suggest naming custom attributes with `data-*`according to the HTML5 spec like this:

```
<div data-htmllable></div>
```

Your can then access the value of the attribute in two ways (jQuery 1.4.3+):

```
var val1 = $(this).attr('data-htmllabel');
var val2 = $(this).data('htmllabel');

// Outputs same value //
alert(val1);
alert(val2);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help but what does "alter" method does?